# I wonder what this function really does .split(' ').map(x => +x);

Tags: javascript, dictionary, arrow-functions

I saw this line of code in a correction in a coding game

```
const tC = readline().split(' ').map(x => +x);
```

I wonder what it does because when I log this function it render the same thing that this one

```
const tC = readline().split(' ').map(x => x);
```

but the rest of the code didn't work

Context :

```
/** Temperatures (easy) https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/temperatures
 * Solving this puzzle validates that the loop concept is understood and that
 * you can compare a list of values.
 * This puzzle is also a playground to experiment the concept of lambdas in
 * different programming languages. It's also an opportunity to discover
 * functional programming.
 *
 * Statement:
 * Your program must analyze records of temperatures to find the closest to
 * zero.
 *
 * Story:
 * It's freezing cold out there! Will you be able to find the temperature
 * closest to zero in a set of temperatures readings?
**/
const N = +readline();
const tC = readline().split(' ').map(x => +x);

let min = Infinity;

for (let i in tC) {
    (Math.abs(tC[i]) < Math.abs(min) || tC[i] === -min && tC[i] > 0) && (min = tC[i]);
}

print(min || 0);
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [site](https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/temperatures) below are the inputs the program should receive

Line 1: N, the number of temperatures to analyze

Line 2: A string with the N temperatures expressed as integers ranging from -273 to 5526

Let me provide line by line comments with respect to the game rules

```
// Line 1: reads number temperature inputs. + converts to number
const N = +readline();
// Line 2: reads string of temperatures.
// tC contains an array of temperatures of length N in numbers. + converts to number
const tC = readline().split(' ').map(x => +x);

let min = Infinity;
// iterate over tC array
for (let i in tC) {
    // If two numbers are equally close to zero, positive integer has to be considered closest to zero
    // set min = current iterating number if it matches above condition
    (Math.abs(tC[i]) < Math.abs(min) || tC[i] === -min && tC[i] > 0) && (min = tC[i]);
}

print(min || 0);
```

### Here is the working demo in javascript

modified to make it understandable for beginners.

```js
// Line 1: reads number temperature inputs. + converts to number
// const N = +readline(); SAMPLE ALTERNATIVE
const N = +"5";
// Line 2: reads string of temperatures.
// tC contains an array of temperatures of length N in numbers. + converts to number
// const tC = readline().split(' ').map(x => +x); SAMPLE ALTERNATIVE
const tC = "1 -2 -8 4 5".split(' ').map(x => +x);

let min = Infinity;
// iterate over tC array
for (let i in tC) {
    // If two numbers are equally close to zero, positive integer has to be considered closest to zero
    // set min = current iterating number if it matches above condition
    (Math.abs(tC[i]) < Math.abs(min) || tC[i] === -min && tC[i] > 0) && (min = tC[i]);
}

console.log(min || 0);
```

Comment: I understand but how the for loop returns something ? while there is no min = "something" but only a logic test

Comment: @BenjaminMaine this is called as [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) a special kind of loop for iterating over enumberable properties. Perhaps that line could be rewritten with traditional for loop and forEach

Comment: @BenjaminMaine I have added working version using hard coded values. Please go through this so that you can understand what is happening

Comment: For anyone else wondering where `min` is set, it's set at the end of the line within the loop.  That line is effectively `IF the absolute value of the test value < the absolute value of min OR (the test value = min * -1 AND the test value is positive) THEN set min = the test value`

Answer (score 4):

The `.map(x => +x)` converts all items in the array to a number. And returns a new array with those converted values.

If you change it to `.map(x => x)` then the values are left untouched und you just create a copy of the original array. So the strings remain strings which will break the code if numbers are expected.

I personally would avoid the `+x` syntax and use the more verbose `Number(x)`, and write either `.map(x => Number(x))` or `.map(Number)`.

Comment: Allright, I guess that means that I had strings and it converts to numbers. Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: @BenjaminMaine  yes you have a string and you split that string based on spaces. So you have an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function readLine(){
  return "123456"
}

var result = readLine().split("").map(x => +x)

console.log(result)
```

`readLine().split("")` // **splits the string into an array as follows  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]**

`.map(x => +x)` // **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method returns a new array which will take each item and gives a new array , here number changing from string to numbers as follows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] since +x is used**

// **the above is written in es6, which can be re written in es5 as follows**

```
readLine().split("").map(function(x) {
  return +x
})
```

// **Note**

In es6 if we have a single thing to pass we can avoid the function(x) to x

also we can remove the {} [curly braces and return too]
`{return +x}` to `+x`

**ES2015**

```
readLine().split("").map(function(x) {
  return +x
})
```

**ES2016**

```
readLine().split("").map(x => +x);
```

Comment: I know arrow functions es6, thanks a lot for your very clear explanation !