# How for loop returns something while there is no var = something only a logic test

Tags: for-loop, ecmascript-6

I wonder how for loop returns something while there is no var = something only a logic test

/** Temperatures (easy) https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/temperatures
 * Solving this puzzle validates that the loop concept is understood and that
 * you can compare a list of values.
 * This puzzle is also a playground to experiment the concept of lambdas in
 * different programming languages. It's also an opportunity to discover
 * functional programming.
 *
 * Statement:
 * Your program must analyze records of temperatures to find the closest to
 * zero.
 *
 * Story:
 * It's freezing cold out there! Will you be able to find the temperature
 * closest to zero in a set of temperatures readings?
**/

```
const N = +readline();
const tC = readline().split` `.map(x => +x);

let min = Infinity;

for (let i in tC) {
    (Math.abs(tC[i]) < Math.abs(min) || tC[i] === -min && tC[i] > 0) && (min = 
tC[i]);
}

print(min || 0);
```

Related to : [I wonder what this function really does .split(' ').map(x => +x);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702610/i-wonder-what-this-function-really-does-split-mapx-x/52702804?noredirect=1#comment92332260_52702804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). When we have a series of expressions connected by a logical operator (`&&` for example), the expressions are evaluated from the left, and will stop if the expression is evaluated as `false` for `&&` or `true` for `||`.

In this case, ff the expression `(Math.abs(tC[i]) < Math.abs(min) || tC[i] === -min && tC[i] > 0)` is evaluated as true, then this expression is executed as well `(min = tC[i]);`. The 2nd expression assign the value `tC[i]` to `min` (min was declared before as variable - `let min = Infinity;`).